# Serverless CORS preflight request failed - AWS API Stripe

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services

I have spent about 2 weeks trying to debug this but no luck.

I have created a lambda function using python that creates a charge. This works fine with Stripe Checkout's simple script. It invokes it and returns the response without any issues (Python).

```
  try:

  stripe.api_key = "*******PRIVATE KEY***********"
  Tokenstring = event.get('body')
  Stripe_List = Tokenstring.split('=')
  Token = Stripe_List[1].split('&')[0]
  Email = Stripe_List[-1]
  Email = Email.replace('%40', '@')
  charge = stripe.Charge.create(
     amount=100,
     currency="gbp",
     description="Example charge",
     source=Token,
     receipt_email=Email
  )
  print('Full SUCCESSFUL Transaxn Info ==== {}'.format(event))
  return {
      "statusCode": 302,
      "headers": {
          "Location": "https://example.com/#success"
      }
  }
```

This is invoked very simply in the html body with `<form action="https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/beta" method="POST">`

Now, when I try to use the custom stripe checkout code, I get:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

My javascript code is:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
   key: '*****PRIVATE KEY*****',
   image: 'logo.png',
   locale: 'auto',
   token: function(token) {    
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST","https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/beta", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
           body : token
      }));
   }
 });
```

I have set up OPTIONS in Amazon's API Gateway to respond and have enabled CORS on amazon API gateway.

[image]

[image]

How can I pass the pre-flight request and let lambda execute the function?

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');` definitely does not belong.  That is a response header, not a request header.  `Origin 'null' ...` Are you by chance testing this from a web site at `http://localhost` or from a HTML file on your computer (not a web server)?

Comment: I have tried both @Michael-sqlbot, running on localhost and on my https domain, same issues on both :/!

Comment: It should not be the **exact same** error, and the differences may be significant.  Please show what you see using the https domain, and capture the request and response headers.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I have a try/except, the except redirects to example.com/#error:

HTTPS console log: `Failed to load https://example.com/#error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`   

localhost console log:`Failed to load https://example.com/#error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`

Comment: I'm stumped on the fact that you see `Origin 'null'...`.

Comment: It's okay, I have setup my checkout to use it without using CORS. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from enabling CORS on the API Gateway Console, your Lambda function itself has to return those CORS headers.

```
return {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "headers": {
        "Location": "https://example.com/#success",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    }
}
```